# Solve this inequality: $\sin x<1$

Tags: trigonometry

it may be a simple question, but as simple as it is  I want to know how to solve it:
$$\sin {x}<1$$
What is the solution of this inequality? Thank you!

Comment: hint: -1<=sinx<=1

Comment: You know that $ \sin x \le 1 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $, thus either $ \sin x = 1 $ or $ \sin x < 1 $. Now, $ \sin x = 1 $ if and only if $ x = \pi/2 + 2k\pi $ for integer $ k $, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$$

For real $\displaystyle x,\cos^2x\ge0\implies 1-\sin^2x\ge0\iff -1\le \sin x\le1$

Conversely, if $\displaystyle\sin x>1, \sin^2x>1,\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x<0$

In fact, $\displaystyle\sin x=1\implies =2n\pi+\frac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

So, $\displaystyle x\ne2n\pi+\frac\pi2$

Comment: So the solution for this inequality should be $x<(2k+1)\pi/2$?

Comment: @JohnG., The solution will be any real $x$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is real, but $sin \frac{\pi}{2} = 1 \nless 1$. So it can't be "all real $x$".

Comment: @JohnG., Please find the edited version

Comment: you still miss what is the set of the solution to the inequality $\sin(x) \lt 1$ you are just saying which numbers are not solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to
$$\sin x = 1$$
is $\left\{\ldots,\frac{-11\pi}{2},\frac{-7\pi}{2},\frac{-3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\frac{9\pi}{2},\ldots\right\}$ (why?).

So the solution set to
$$\sin x < 1$$
should be
$$\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{\ldots,\frac{-11\pi}{2},\frac{-7\pi}{2},\frac{-3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\frac{9\pi}{2},\ldots\right\}$$

since, for real $x$, we have $\sin x < 1$ if just $\sin x\ne 1$.